# How to find which group is matched in NSRegularExpression

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I have a regex statement with multiple capture groups which are separated by | operator. How can I find out which capture group is matched? Only way I can think of -for this example- is counting the number of characters if something is matched.

```
var string = "1234567897"
var pattern = "(^\\d{9}$)|(^\\d{10}$)|(^\\d{13}$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$)"

var myRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)!

if let myMatch = myRegex.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil,
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16Count)) {
        println((string as NSString).substringWithRange(myMatch.rangeAtIndex(0)))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a code which worked for my example. I am sure it can be written better way but it works for now.

**Swift 2.3**

```
var string = "123456789"
var pattern = "(^\\d{9}$)|(^\\d{10}$)|(^\\d{13}$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{9}[wW]{2}$)"

var myRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

if let myMatch = myRegex.firstMatchInString(string, options: NSMatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)) {
    var matchedGroup = 0

    for var i in 1..<myMatch.numberOfRanges {
        if myMatch.rangeAtIndex(i).length != 0 {
            matchedGroup = i
            break
        }

    }
    print(matchedGroup)
    print((string as NSString).substringWithRange(myMatch.rangeAtIndex(0))) //whatever the range you want to print

}
```

**Swift 3**

```
var string = "123456789"
var pattern = "(^\\d{9}$)|(^\\d{10}$)|(^\\d{13}$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{9}[wW]{2}$)"

var myRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

if let myMatch = myRegex.firstMatch(in: string, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)) {
    var matchedGroup = 0

    for var i in 1..<myMatch.numberOfRanges {
        if myMatch.rangeAt(i).length != 0 {
            matchedGroup = i
            break
        }

    }
    print(matchedGroup)
    print((string as NSString).substring(with: myMatch.rangeAt(0))) //whatever the range you want to print

}
```